# Cannot export SELECT result as expected

Tags: oracle

I noticed this issue when exporting the Oracle SQL execution result from Intellij.

The database version is: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.

My SQL is

```
SELECT TableA.seq||'-'||TableB.id doc_id
FROM schemaA.TableA
JOIN schemaB.TableB
JOIN schemaA.TableC
JOIN schemaA.TableD ON ...
```

The result of `SELECT COUNT(doc_id)` is 137272, however, the exported CSV file has less than 137272 (sometimes 137258, not fixed) lines.

I checked the result and to my surprise found that there are duplicated `doc_id` which was not expected.

But if I add `ORDER BY doc_id` to the SQL statement and re-export the result, everything becomes fine.

I have also used SQL*PLUS to export to CSV, but encountered a similar situation.

I thought it might be caused by paging, so I wrote a Java program to get the data. No luck, the output file also has less than 137272 lines, and with some duplicated lines.

If I change the FetchSize to 1000, sometimes the result is OK. If the fetchsize is 100, it is always wrong.

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_CONNECTION,
        JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWORD)) {
    try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement(); FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("out.txt")) {
        statement.setFetchSize(100);

        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                fw.write(rs.getString(1));
                fw.write("\n");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // not shown in this code snippet
        }
    }
}
```

I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806784/oracle-jdbc-resultset-doesnt-return-correct-data-set), and someone suggested to me to ask in stackexchange, so I ask again here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try PL/SQL? With FOR loops, Oracle performs implicit bulk collects of 100 rows at a time, as per [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-cursors).

Make sure you are doing the `order by` in your select, as you said this gave you the correct results.  I also recommend you to clean your duplicates.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare 
  cursor c1 is
    select <YOUR SELECT>
begin   
  for c in c1 loop 
    null;
  end loop;  
end;
/
```